# How to use Json.net to read an array from a json file?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I've done my research and I've found several solutions to problems that are almost the same as mine but none of them have worked so far. What I'm trying to accomplish is to read a json file where the first item is an array, like this:

```
{
"the_array":[
```

The error I get is:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The closest I've gotten is when I try to write out the entire json but then I only get the first item in the array. [edit: clarification below]

Here's the code:

### Program.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace JsonToXML
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string json = File.ReadAllText(@"w:\code\csharp\JsonToXML\simple-sample.json").ToString();

            Accounts accs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Accounts>(json);

          foreach (var acc in accs.account_list)
           {
            Console.Write(acc.id.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

}

### Accounts.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JsonToXML
{
class Accounts
{
    public List<accounts> account_list { get; set; }

    public class accounts
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string bic { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

### simple_sample.json

```
{
"account_list": [
    {
        "id": "AsdF01234EfgH4567",
        "bic": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": "AbcD1234eFgH568",
        "bic": "B"
    },
    {
        "id": "Baas786DD5886RT",
        "bic": "C"
    },
    {
        "id": "458A889B8889T784W",
        "bic": "D"
    }
]
```

}

I've also tried using `List<Accounts>` with no success.

If anything about the question is unclear, just let me know and I'll clarify as best I can.

I'm coding this in .Net Core

[edit: clarification from above]
If I try:

```
var accs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
Console.Write(accs.ToString());
```

The result is:
    {
    "id": "AsdF01234EfgH4567",
    "bic": "SWEDSESS"
    }

---

## Solved

The problem was within the json file. While it looked like it worked, somehow sublime had saved it incorrectly. After remaking the json file with the exact same content, it worked as intended.

Comment: Shouldn't `public string bic` be `public string name`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Try using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);` and see what that brings back. It'll give you a good indication on what the deserialization process is actually trying to do, which can point you in the right direction.

Comment: did you try .toList()?

Comment: @RubyHaus I realised I didn't explain that bit well at all. I did try that and I've added the result to the question since I can't figure out why the result is what it is.

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI What I've tried is:
Accounts accs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Accounts>(json); ||| 

List<Accounts> accs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Accounts>>(json); ||| 

var accs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json); 

I'm not sure how to implement .ToList() here.

Comment: ok i give you solution wait please

Comment: @zaitsman I've checked that possible duplicate before posting but couldn't figure out why I get the exception. I've been racking my brain, hoping that I've just missed something very simple, but after 12 hours of fighting and comparing what have helped others with similar problems I finally accepted that I need help solving this. When I figure this out I'll go back to that solution and see if I can use that to further explain where I went wrong for others that encounters the same issue.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, I changed bic to name before posting here but forgot to change it in code as well. It is not part of the problem but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: so you just want to print all ids only?

Comment: nothing wrong with this code ? this is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple you only **GET FIRST** because this `

**Console.ReadKey(true)`**

Readkey is used to wait for user key press so it wont execute further until you press some key read [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Final Code**

```
  try
        {
  string json = File.ReadAllText(@"w:\code\csharp\JsonToXML\simple-sample.json").ToString();

            Accounts accs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Accounts>(json);

            foreach (var acc in accs.account_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(acc.id.ToString());


            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
           throw ex;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: For me, this is still not working and throwing: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Are you running this as a Microsoft.NetCore.App and it's working for you?

Comment: I got it working now by remaking the json file. Seems to be an issue with how sublime saved the json file. Editing the question to include the solution.

Comment: @Thomas I have tested this code in both .net core and .net version, and its working fine.